# IE 9 nested form in accordion black screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation's accordion js.  I have no issue creating a form in viewing it in chrome however in IE v 9 the whole page is black besides footer links.  For my site, I include the same header and footer throughout the site which is why I found it interesting that the issue only occurs on this page.

I am working on finding some developer's tools on IE but until then I wanted to reach out and see if anyone has ran into this problem.  I believe is has to do with the jquery and css because while the page loads you can see the normal layout however afterwards the page is black.

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loading').hide();                   
  $('div.container div').show();   
  $(".active").trigger('click');
});
```

Here is the link to the issue, remember this is only occurring in ie v 9: http://rppdesigns.com/dev/pennProp_dev/index.php/home/contact

Comment: _I am working on finding some developer's tools on IE_ -> F12

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for developer"s tools, I can strongly recommend www.projectseven.com. Their accordion tool is amazing.  I use it all the time, and it works just as well on iPads and mobiles and adapts to device rotation etc and you can control it with events.

Barry